# Resolve overflow in HTML table with image

Tags: html, css, html-table

Following is the code structure of my HTML table. I insert a large image in `tr class c0` (marked by `*...*`). The class `no-overflow` has `overflow:auto`. In other pages, using the same class `no-overflow` there are horizontal and vertical scroll bars if the image gets big. However, in this particular case, the bars do not appear.

```
 <table class="someclass" width="60%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th class="header c0" style="text-align:left;">Content: Test 1</th>
        <th class="header c1">Class Statistics</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        **<tr class="r0">
            <td class="cell c0" style="text-align:left;">Question: <br>
                <div class="no-overflow">
                    <div class="no-overflow">
                        <p><img src="image path" width="1365" height="767"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="cell c1" style=""> </td>
        </tr>**
        <tr class="r1">
            <td class="cell c0" style="text-align:left;">Answer:</td>
            <td class="cell c1" style=""> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="r0">
            <td class="cell c0" style="text-align:left;"><input type="button" name="1" value="Next"> Next </td>
            <td class="cell c1" style=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="r1 lastrow">
            <td class="cell c0" style="text-align:left;"></td>
            <td class="cell c1" style=""> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Table Image:

[image: Table Image]

Comment: have you tried adding a fix `width` on your `<div class="no-overflow">` ?

Comment: please make a fiddle and share your code there.

Answer (score 0):

`overflow:auto` by itself on a table-cell isn't going to do anything, unfortunately. Table cells will resize themselves to allow them to fit their contents. However, if you add a fixed `width` and `height` to the table cell, the overflow works fine and the scroll bars are visible.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ne6w5/).